# mysql extract_json value from array

Tags: mysql, arrays, json

I have a MySQL DB containing a table named "products".
This table contains a Json Data_type column named "values".

I would like to find the path to extract a specific value :

> select JSON_EXTRACT(values, '$.COD')
>   from products
>   where id = '1'

returns :

```
"COD": {"<channels>": {"<locales>": "3699999999999"}}
```

And what I want is "3699999999999".

It is pretty obvious that my path is not the good one, but I can't find the solution.

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Hello and welcome. As newcomer reading of [ask] and [mcve] is good practice to learn how to ask a good question. For this case, you should provide the table schema.

Comment: try with `$.COD.<locales>`

Comment: Thank you,
I tried, but I get an error regarding the '<' and '>' chars : "Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 26."

Comment: Try [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=128ce477e4a04b00c8e601c415c5d239).

Comment: You rock wchiquito !
How did I miss it ? Anyway, is there a way to select your answer as solution ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(`values`, '$.COD.<channels>.<locales>') FROM products WHERE id = '1';
```

For more details please refer [mysql-for-your-json](https://www.compose.com/articles/mysql-for-your-json/)

Comment: Thanks,
I tried it but I get an error regarding the special chars '<' and '>'.
"Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 26."

Comment: Could you please try with backticks as `<channels>`.`<locales>`

Comment: Thanks again, I tried --->
 select JSON_EXTRACT(values, '$.COD.`<channels`>.`<locales`>')   
and ---->
JSON_EXTRACT(values, '$.COD.`<channels>`.`<locales>`') 
but same error twice.